# Minimizing KL divergence: the asymmetry, when will the solution be the same?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, it.information-theory, calculus-of-variations

The KL divergence between two distribution $p$ and $q$ is defined as
$$
D( q \| p)\int q(x)\log \frac{q(x)}{p(x)} dx
$$
and is known to be asymmetry: $D(q\|p)\neq D(p\|q)$.

If we fix $p$ and try to find a distribution $q$ among a class $E$ that minimize the KL distance, it is also known that minimizing  $D( q \| p)$ will be different from minimizing  $D( p \| q)$, e.g., https://benmoran.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/kullback-leibler-divergence-asymmetry/.

It is not clear which one to be optimized for a better approximation, although in many application we minimize $D(q\|p)$.

My question is that, when will the solution be the same

$$
\underset{q\in E}{\operatorname{argmin}} D(q\|p) = \underset{q\in E}{\operatorname{argmin}} D(p\|q)?
$$

For instance, if we take $E$ as the class of all Gaussian distribution, is there a condition on $p$ so that minimizing these two will lead to the same minimizer?

Comment: I'm a little confused: isn't $D(q || p)$ minimized at $q = p$ since $p \log \frac{p}{p} = 0$?  Isn't it more normal to maximize KL-divergence?

Comment: Well, OP minimizes over a constraint set $E$, i.e. seeking the "closest distribution to $p$ that comes from $E$". Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a definite answer, but here is something to continue with:

Formulate the optimization problems with constraints as
$$
\mathrm{argmin}_{F(q)=0} D(q || p),\qquad \mathrm{argmin}_{F(q)=0} D(p||q)
$$
and form the respective Lagrange functionals. Using that the derivatives of $D$ w.r.t. to the first and second components are, respectively,
$$
\nabla_1 D(q||p) = \log(\tfrac{q}{p})+1\quad\text{and}\quad \nabla_2 D(p||q) = \tfrac{q}{p}
$$ you see that necessary conditions for optima $q^*$ and $q^{**}$, respectively, are
$$
\log(\tfrac{q^*}{p})+1 + \nabla F(q^*)\lambda = 0\quad\text{and}\quad  \tfrac{q^{**}}{p} + \nabla F(q^{**})\lambda = 0.
$$
I would not expect that $q^*$ and $q^{**}$ are equal for any non-trivial constraint…

On the positive side, $\nabla_1 D(q||p)$ and $\nabla_2 D(q||p)$ agree up to first order at $p=q$, i.e. $$\nabla_1 D(q||p) = \nabla_2 D(q||p) + \mathcal{O}(\tfrac{q}{p})$$.

Comment: I think there is a symmetrized version of KL divergence if the OP wants symmetry so much... But the motivation of doing so is not very clear as he described.

Comment: Yes, it's simply $(D(p||q)+D(q||p))/2.$